# LDAP Attributes case modified without consent

Tags: ldap, openldap, shibboleth

I have an LDAP server (Openldap 2.4.42) which is only accessed with writing rights by a Symfony 2.8 application and reading rights from a 3.2 Shibboleth IDP.

Overnight, without any script in the application needing to do that, some of my user attributes names were changed from Camel to uppercase. For exemple, I had eduPrimaryAffiliation and this morning it had became EDUPRIMARYAFFILIATION.

If any of you could point me in a direction, I will gladly give more information if needed, I think that is the basics needed to study the problem but feel free to ask for more.

Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're seeing this upper-case attribute name in output of *slapcat*. Right?

This usually happens if schema was removed from the OpenLDAP server's configuration and some attributes using this schema are still there. *slapcat* will then export these attributes with upper-case names (instead of the original camel-cased attribute name in the schema).